# select count based on year based on field

Tags: php

I am trying to put together a query so that when I add a record, the database assigns it a sequential number based on how many records there are in the next year, then adding the next number, e.g.

2016/1
2016/2

This is the query I have so far:

```
CustomQuery("Select Count(*) as count1 from ApplicationRegister where ClientFk='".$values['ClientFk']."' AND ???
```

What I want is to use the 2nd logic operator to say `YEAR(now)=Year(ApplicationDate)`, where ApplicationDate is a date field within the database.

How do  do this?

Comment: might have just seen answer in another question, would...YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())  be the answer?

Comment: Yes, that should do it. Although that is what you have in the question already, did it not work as expected?

Comment: no i just didnt realise when i was describing what i was wanting, that it was actually the right code, bit of a fluke

Comment: although it is coming up with an error?

Comment: CustomQuery("Select Count(*) as count1 from ApplicationRegister where ClientFk='".$values['ClientFk']."' AND YEAR($applicationdate) = YEAR(CURDATE())");

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: just the standard Error type 256, am looking through it now

Comment: Call to undefined function Year()

Comment: The `year()` call is in quotes right, or you are using it in PHP? Can you update the question with your code?

Comment: its ok its sorted, i was trying to echo it earier without turning into strtotime, all good now, thanks anyway